# Fontawesome with @counter-style css properties

Tags: css, font-awesome

I can't get the fontawesome icons to work with a @counter-style. I have the famous squares containing the unicode... I have added the appropriate font-family property. Is there a possibility?
If not, I'll see if I can use the svg of the icons, it should work I suppose, but it's a shame...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"/>

list-style: icone;
family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
font-weight: 900;
```

and

```css
@counter-style icone {
    system: additive;
    additive-symbols: "\f0ca" 1;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working but its a shame you wrote  `family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";` instead of `font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";`

```css
li {
  list-style: icone;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}

@counter-style icone {
  system: additive;
  additive-symbols: "\f0ca" 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>world</li>
  <li>love</li>
  <li>coding</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: okay yes, thank you so much.
I have trouble copying and pasting.
Otherwise, for it to work for me, I had to add a content: (counter(step, icone)).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I copied and pasted it wrong but it was right in my code.
I have no idea why it didn't work, but I was able to apply it to a pseudo-element with the help of another, related question. Thanks to you.